# How to change text position

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi. How to change the text position. I want to change the Personal Information text in line with the first name. I tried to use Widget padding but it didn't work.

Code

```
Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        //margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, <=
                          children: [
                           /* SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),*/
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                'Personal Information',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18,),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(height: 35),
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1000
                                          ? 1000
                                          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 25,
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'First Name',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 400,
                                                  child: TextFormField(
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.black),
                                                    controller: firstName,
                                                    onSaved: (String? value) {
                                                      firstName.text = value!;
                                                    },
                                                    decoration:
                                                        const InputDecoration(
                                                      border:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                            width: 1,
                                                            color:
                                                                Color.fromRGBO(
                                                                    217,
                                                                    217,
                                                                    217,
                                                                    1)),
                                                      ),
                                                      hintText: '* First Name',
                                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                                          fontSize: 16),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
),
```

If I change crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, to CrossAxisAlignment.start my TextFormField also changes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you properly format your code and paste it here formatted? It's very hard to understand the code when it is not properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Multiple columns which is causing this. From the code i don't see why we need Multiple columns. You can create a single Column as a child for the container and Style the child widgets accordingly.
This Would be the best way to implement it.

You can give the alignment Property to the parent container. And update the style of child widget if it adheres to different styles.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `Column` and put its children's in the first one. Then use `Align` widget over the column to bring it to the center. Or you may try giving the `alignment` parameter to Container, I'm not much sure of this.

The hierarchy would be such:

```
Container() => Align() => Column(children: [all the children of both old columns])
```